# MS PowerAutomate check if file exists in Onedrive and rename

Tags: power-automate

I have a following process to automate in my PA:
When email arrives to outlook's specific folder, save email's attachment to Onedrive folder.

Problem: attachment files often have same names, despite different content.

I need either to :

1. Check if file with same name already exists in onedrive, if so - add counter or something, like 'file_2..3..4'
2. Or probably easier - Save attachment file with date, like 'attachment_dd.mm.yy.xlsx'

How could this be achieved properly?

Currently, I have tried the 2nd options, with filename concat with emails date, but perhaps there is a better way:

[image: Flow]

[image: Flow_2]

Comment: Does your current approach work? If so, maybe just go with it. There’s no right answer for what you’re doing.

Comment: I agree with Skin. Your current approach with the concat function and using the receivedDateTime looks fine :)

Comment: I was hoping to find way to approach option #1 with file check, but second option is ok as well :)